# unknown notification icon on HTC One M9 Android 7

Tags: notification-icons

i´ve just installed Android 7 and this icon on the top left appeared, i want to know what it is, also i dont have any apps whith that icon..[image]

my phone is a HTC one M9

Comment: If you pull down the notification menu is there a corresponding notification message? If you long-press the message does it give an app name?

Answer (score 1):

It's the Peel notification. Its a remote app that comes pre installed on some devices. The notification lets you power off, change volume and go to the app.

Answer (score 0):

its a peel remote control icon, if you want to remove it simply uninstall the app by going to setting> app manager> and remove the app.